# Multiple app domains in w3wp when using serivceAutoStartProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, iis-7.5

We are using the **serviceAutoStartProvider** functionality in IIS to launch worker threads without the need for a request to trigger the startup code. We do that in a **.NET 4.5.2 WebApi application using the IProcessHostPreloadClient** implementation.

This application is deployed to a Windows 2008 R2 server where a dozen web applications are hosted under the same main site. All applications use a separate .NET 4.0 Integrated app pool (with the ApplicationPoolIdentity).

We use the following appcmd.exe commands to configure out WebApi application:

```
appcmd.exe clear config -section:system.applicationHost/serviceAutoStartProviders -commit:apphost
appcmd.exe set config -section:system.applicationHost/serviceAutoStartProviders /+"[name='MyAutoStartup',type='WorkerHost.StartupClient, WorkerHostAssembly, version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null']" /commit:apphost
appcmd.exe set apppool "WorkerHostPool" /autoStart:"true" /startMode:"AlwaysRunning" /processModel.idleTimeout:00:00:00
appcmd.exe set app "Default Web Site/WorkerHost" /serviceAutoStartProvider:"MyHostAutoStartup" /serviceAutoStartEnabled:"true"
```

We have observed that **serveral w3wp.exe processes have three app domains loaded**: the SharedDomain Appdomain, the app domain for the one of the web applications, **and a thrid app domain for the web application that uses the autoStart functionaltiy!**

Why is that happening? And more importantly, **how can this be prevented?**

Comment: You should be very careful with launching your own threads in ASP.NET. In fact, you probably shouldn't do it at all. Instead, use a library that's been specifically assigned to account for the pitfalls of background processing in ASP.NET. See [Scott Hanselman's excellent blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx) on the subject.

Comment: @mason I am aware of that excellent article and was considering using HangFire, but my group prefers to not take on another external dependency. We are using the QueueBackgroundWorkItem() API mentioned in that article.

Comment: did you find an answer?